# Detect if user has scrolled to the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery)

I have a page where I have a header, left menu, content, right menu and a footer. Inside my content I have a div (say id-foo) where I have some data. When user scrolls the page and reaches the bottom of div I have to make an ajax call and bring more data to fill the content there. How can I detect that user has scrolled(page scroll, there is no scroll in div) to bottom of div (foo) .

Comment: First result in the google search - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery

Comment: My div is not having scroll. I have clearly mentioned it.

Comment: @RockySingh Is there a principal difference between scrolling a `div` and scrollin a `body`?

Comment: @Rocky Singh It is pretty much the same concept though. The same solution should work for you with very little tweeking.

Comment: @RockySingh - You can apply the same logic on document scroll as well.

Comment: Neither is the one within the link; if you read through it, you'll see it is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have to do some math yourself, based on the current screen size and the div position. The code will look roughly like this (untested):

```
// Cache these values. If the div size changes, divBottom will need to be recalculated.
var $div = $("#yourdiv");
var divBottom = $div.offset().top + parseInt($div.height());

// Bind a scroll event for the whole page
$("body").bind("scroll", function(e)
{
    // Calculate how far down the user has scrolled
    var screenBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + parseInt($(window).height());

    // Test if the div has been revealed
    if(screenBottom > divBottom)
    {
        // do something
    }
});
```