# JQuery Mobile LazyLoad Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, lazy-loading

So I'm doing lazy loading on a ListView on one jQuery page.  When you click the ListItem it takes you to a details page.  The problem is, that since I've binded a `scrollstop` event to the window, that the lazy load still tries to fire on the details page.

```
$("#index").on("pageshow", function () {
  //get initial list view data

  var inital = $('#filters').serialize(); //gets 'filter' params for data-access
  RetrieveMeetings(inital);  //Populate initial set

  //lazy load
  //Window Event From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983835/detect-if-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom-of-a-div
  $(window).bind('scrollstop', function () { //this also fires on details page!!!
    var screenBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + parseInt($(window).height());
    var $div = $('#meetings-list');
    var divBottom = $div.offset().top + parseInt($div.height());

    if (screenBottom > divBottom) {
       var values = $('#filters').serialize();
       LoadMoreMeetings(values);
    }
  });

  //new dataset from filter forum
  $("#submit").click(function (event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    var values = $('#filters').serialize();
    ResetMeetingList();
    RetrieveMeetings();

  });

});
```

I could fix this by removing the `page` from the DOM on the `pagehide` event but then I lose page state of a filter forums and such whenever the user returns to the ListView (also it increases pageload time).

```
    //remove pages from DOM on hide
    $(document).on("pagehide", function (e) {
        $(e.target).remove();
    });
```

Is there someway to attach the `scrollstop` event to the `page` instead of the `window`?

Another issue with this method is that if the Screen is big enough to load the page without a scroll bar then the lazy load obviously wont fire!   Maybe there's a better overall solution for this problem?