# How to find out if the user scrolled to the end of a HTML container with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

how do I find out if the user scrolled up to the top or down to the bottom in a scrollable container?

Does jQuery offer any mechanisms?

css:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    background: green;
}
#scrolling {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    backround: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hmaf2/2/

Thanks a lot!

Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the scroll position [by comparing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery) the height, scrollable height and scroll offset of the div:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scrolling').scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var iheight = $(this).innerHeight();
        var sheight = this.scrollHeight;
        var text = '';
        if (scrollTop <= 5) {
            text = 'top';
        }
        else if (scrollTop+5 >= sheight-iheight) {
            text = 'bottom';
        }
        else {
            text = scrollTop+' middle ('+iheight+','+sheight+')';
        }
        $('#result').text(text);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmaf2/6/)
This example has reserved 5 pixels from the top and bottom of the div's margin.

Comment: awesome! this is exactly the solution I needed!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#somediv').scrollTop()
```

will tell you the position from the top

-edit-

```
$('#somediv').scroll(function(){
    if($('#somediv').scrollTop()==0){
        console.log('top')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can access the current [scroll top](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) value of a scrollable container.

[Here working is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmaf2/4/)

```
$('#scrolling').scroll(function() {
   var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
   console.log(scrollTop);
});​
```

Comment: [Here is a jsFiddle with console.log opened ready.](http://jsfiddle.net/B3F4X/3/)