# Is it possible to add iscroll library in div contend using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me that is this possible to add iscroll in div contend using jquery mobile. I found this solution
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/introduction-to-iscroll/
But It not work for me .Actually I know jQuery having default iscroll .But it works fine in IOS But not in android so I need to add iscroll in android.

I need to add iscroll in given div.
http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/45DB9/

```
<div id="realTimeContents" class ="left realtimeContend_h" style="width:100%"> 
                         Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar AM (Listeni/səˈtʃɪn tɛnˈduːlkər/; born 24 April 1973)[1] is an Indian cricketer widely
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT #1 Scrolls div contents instead of list items**

**EDIT #2: Alerts when contents are scrolled to the end**

This is how I setup iScroll in JQM.  It also works fine in my Android device

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="iscroll.js"></script>

<script>
    var myScroll;

    // -- pageinit event that fires for SPECIFIC PAGE ONLY --
    // -- this code is executed only once upon initital page load (or if it is no longer in the cache)
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#example_page_one", function() {

        // iScroll uses the following in their examples but if we did that in a JQM
        // site then normal mobile scrolling would be disabled on EVERY PAGE :-(
        //      document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

        // Instead, we disable normal mobile scrolling for the JQM 'page' that we are using iScroll in
        $('#example_page_one').on('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault; });

        // edit #2: will look for and alert when end of contents are reached
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
              onScrollEnd: function() {
                    if(($('#wrapper').offset().top - $('#scroller').offset().top) + $('#wrapper').height() >= $('#scroller').height()){
                        alert('the end');
                    }                        

              }
        });

    });
</script>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="example_page_one" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">


<style type="text/css">

#wrapper {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
    top:45px; bottom:48px; left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#aaa;
    overflow:auto;
}

#scroller {
    position:absolute; z-index:1;
/*  -webkit-touch-callout:none;*/
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
}

#scroller ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}

#scroller li {
    padding:0 10px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">

        <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla orci eu vehicula viverra. Aliquam scelerisque purus eleifend ipsum facilisis, vitae auctor erat laoreet. Phasellus imperdiet dolor vel accumsan rutrum. Donec nec neque in orci malesuada tincidunt. Etiam blandit sodales mauris eget vestibulum. Etiam tempor, nulla sed ultricies dignissim, enim lacus pretium tortor, ac fringilla arcu dui at est. Ut sollicitudin et tellus vel blandit. Nunc lacinia metus varius dolor varius dictum. Curabitur accumsan felis ac augue dignissim sollicitudin. Integer feugiat augue nec purus vehicula aliquet. Ut lacinia leo semper mauris lacinia, vel varius urna lacinia. Fusce gravida metus nec scelerisque sodales. Etiam malesuada orci nec laoreet sodales. Sed ac lobortis metus. Nulla eu accumsan elit, blandit vehicula leo. Praesent tristique metus sit amet nulla dapibus, accumsan sagittis odio ullamcorper.
        Sed dapibus mattis mi. Ut eu metus sem. In gravida non dolor nec pulvinar. Suspendisse egestas mauris mattis pulvinar pharetra. In euismod libero sed euismod adipiscing. Etiam et mauris odio. Phasellus et tincidunt libero. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam sed metus ultricies, bibendum urna in, venenatis est. In vestibulum at mauris ac aliquam. Nunc lobortis metus enim, sed scelerisque nisi ullamcorper non. Donec velit metus, mollis ut arcu ac, varius semper risus. Sed vehicula pharetra quam, non adipiscing ligula fringilla sit amet. Vivamus tincidunt urna eu elit tincidunt dignissim.
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



</div>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But you create ul li .I need for a single div

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Anything you put inside the "scroller" div will scroll (if all the contents don't fit in the viewable area).  I removed the <ul id="thelist">..</ul> and replaced it with a div of several paragraphs of lorum ipsum and it scrolls the div contents as expected

Comment: ya I check it fine ..Is there any way to check end of contend .I need to get event if I am end of contend. I want  to show an alert using iscroll

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery

Comment: I tried it and no it really wasn't.  However,  I played around and figured it out.  I have updated my answer to include how you would look for end of content when scrolling.  (However, you really should ask that in a separate question since it's not related to your original.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35926/discussion-between-rohit-and-drew)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [iScrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview). It's a plugin for jQuery mobile, that provides you with ability to set an iScroll with simple data attribute binding.