# What does jQuery(function($){something}); do?

Tags: jquery

I've never seen anyone do this before. Could anyone enlighten me on this? This was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery).

```
jQuery(function ($) { //What's with the $ as an argument?
    $('#flux').bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert('end reached');
        }
    })
});
```

It appears he can declare a function and run it at the same time.

Comment: Is this question about the "$" argument only, or is this the first time you encounter jQuery code?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @ArlaudPierre No sir, I wasn't aware that this was another way to do $(document).ready();. On another note, I just tested the function without the $ argument and it works regardless. Does it serve any purpose?

Comment: @Geoyws check out the discussion I had with Misiur on his answer, it's here "to avoid conflicts with some other global $ variable".

Answer (score 2):

It's shorthand for http://api.jquery.com/ready/

The argument $ is in fact jQuery - it's often used to avoid conflicts with some other global $ variable

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

Comment: No example of the page uses "$" as the function argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but in the second link the last example uses $ as an argument. It's kinda like closures, where you pass global variables, but aliased: ```(function($, hello,  undefined) { /* ... */ })(jQuery, 'something');```

Comment: Oh okay, I only check it on the ready page, my bad. Do we know of any other plugin that conflicts with jQuery?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ - prototype used to be a big problem, also better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 0):

> It appears he can declare a function and run it at the same time.

The function is not run here, it is just passed to `jQuery` (which will run it when the document is ready).

> function ($) { //What's with the $ as an argument?

This is the Javascript concept of a module:

Instead of having the function refer to a global `$` (which may end up being something unexpected), you pass in the `$` as a parameter (jQuery will do that for you here).
Then within the function body `$` refers to that local object.

> I just tested the function without the $ argument and it works regardless.

Yes, but that is because you also have a global object `$`. The idea of passing it in explicitly is to avoid having the function access the global scope.