# Scrollsection Plugin stops inner scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tw7h1xkp/3/)**

**Problem:** I am using **[ScrollSection](https://github.com/guins/jQuery.scrollSections)** plugin & having a problem with inner div scroll. i.e inside a section there is a div with scroll but when i hover over it to scroll the div, it scrolls the page instead.

**What I have tried:** I have added a global Boolean variable(named `disableScrollSectionMouseWheel`) inside the core file of scrollSection plugin which can pause it's functionality of mouse-wheel, Using this switch i have added an event for mouse enter and leave on div, it does stops the page scroll but does not turn on the div scroll!!.

By the way i have created a simple version of this issue in jsFiddle but later i have to integrate it with scroll-magic on this **[site](http://dev.apptestonline.com/opco)**.

**CODE:**

```
$(function() {
    disableScrollSectionMouseWheel = 0;
    scrollSectionsController = $('section.scrollsections').scrollSections({
        speed: 2000,
        touch: false,
        mousewheel: true,
        exceptions: true,
        scrollMax: 1,
        exceptions: true,
        alwaysStartWithFirstSection: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
    /* My Script To pause on hover */
    $('section.scrollsections .title').hover(function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasScrollBar()) {
            disableScrollSectionMouseWheel = 1;
        }
    });
    $('section.scrollsections .title').mouseleave(function(e) {
        disableScrollSectionMouseWheel = 0;
    });
});
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() {
        return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Or you can simple use [`fullPage.js`](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead and the option `normalScrollElements`.

Comment: Full Page JS doesn't uses browser scrolls which means i cant use it with plugins like [scrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) ~ any ways issue was resolved thanks to @Dmitry

Comment: It actually does nowadays. Check out the option `scrollBar`, [there's an example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html) with it.

Comment: In any case, using scrollMagic doesn't make much sense as there are callbacks in fullPage.js for it. But if you still want to use it, you can if you use `scrollBar:true`.

Comment: @Alvaro Nice ~ I didn't knew that, i will definitely use this in my next project. Looks much more promising then [scrollSection](https://github.com/guins/jQuery.scrollSections) which is kind of a dead plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tw7h1xkp/7/

**1.** Plugin stops the `mousewheel` event all the time, so you need to add a condition that checks your variable:

```
 if(disableScrollSectionMouseWheel) return;//line 455 in my fiddle
```

**2.** `.title` does not have the scroll but the `p` inside of it has. So you need to add the event handler to the `p`:

```
$('section.scrollsections .title p')
```

**EDIT:**
Also you need to re-enable the plugin when user scrolls to the bottom or top of the `p`:

```
    $('section.scrollsections .title p').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
            disableScrollSectionMouseWheel = 0;
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
            disableScrollSectionMouseWheel = 0;
        }
    });
```

based on [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery)

Comment: Your code makes a weird flicker when you scroll on the `p` **right after** you scroll outside. When you detect a scroll on the `p` maybe you should cancel the animation?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, There was an animation flick when scrolling top (when inside the `p`). I have updated your answer.