# How do I detect that a div with overflow has scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="item-group" class="scroll-box"></div>

.scroll-box {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}
```

I want to load items as the user scrolls. I've been facilitating this by detecting when they scroll to the bottom of the screen. I've been trying to do the same with the a `div` element and can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the jquery script I wrote recently to get 9gag posts as I scroll. I hope it helps you:

**Note** the magic for the check if you have scrolled to the bottom happens in `$(window).scroll` function

```
<script>
    var nextPageId = '0'
        function loadNextPage(){
            $.getJSON("http://infinigag.eu01.aws.af.cm/trending/"+nextPageId, function(response){
                $.each(response.data, function(){
                    var $img = $('<img/>', {src: this.images.large})
                    $('body').append($img)
                })
                nextPageId = response.paging.next
            })
        }
        loadNextPage()
        var debounceNextPage = debounce(loadNextPage, 100)

        var $document = $(document)
        var $window = $(window)
        $(window).scroll(function(e){
            // console.log(e)
            if($document.height() - $window.scrollTop() == $window.height()){
                console.log("bottom");

                // loadNextPage()
                debounceNextPage()
            }
        })
        // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
        // be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
        // N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
        // leading edge, instead of the trailing.
        function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
            var timeout;
            return function() {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                var later = function() {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
                };
                var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
                if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
            };
        };
    </script>
```

**EDIT**

```
$(".box").scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        $("span").show();    
    } else {
        $("span").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(window).scroll` is never fired when you are scrolling a `div`. I know how to hook `$(window).scroll`.

Comment: I tried that. My problem, I believe, is that I am rendering this content after load.

Comment: Yup, that was my problem. Thanks.