# check if page at a certain section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a function when the user is on a section of the page with a specific ID (either through a link or scroll). This is what I have now but it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname == '/index.html#contact') {
        console.log('Viewing contact form');
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Found what I was looking for. This is what I used:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#contact').offset().top - 50) {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

The "- 50" is to account for my margins and paddings. When using the subtract symbol it 'assumes' your section starts higher on your page. For lower, use addition.
The "$('.modal').modal('hide');" is not needed. This is to hide a bootstrap modal when the user is on the #contact section of the page.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery

Comment: @Katerina: no, it doesn't seem to be. That question asks how to know when the user has scrolled to the bottom of a given element, whereas this question wants to know - so far as I can tell - when a given element is visible on the page, and how to log, or otherwise act upon, that information.

Comment: it's the same, look: if user sees the element, he has scrolled to it) the only difference – you should check this on pageload before user first scrolled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window.location` property in Javascript returns a *location object*. If you want to match a specific anchor link you need to use the `hash` property of the location object. Here's a list of all properties of location objects: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp.

You could check for `window.location.pathname+window.location.hash`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname+window.location.hash == '/index.html#contact') {
        console.log('Viewing contact form');
    }
});
```

because `window.location.pathname` does not include the part after the hash.

Comment: Nice fix. I updated the post with what I'm using but yours works just as well

Answer (score 1):

Your Html code

```
<div id="contact">

</div>
```

Your Javascript code

```
 $("#contact").scroll(function() {
/*do whatever you want*/
    });
```

Comment: I think it's the "*whatever [he wants]*" part that the OP wants help with.