# Why my jQuery scoll event doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie in jQuery. Basically, I need to write a query for lazy loading on a page. I found this post: [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery) and I wanted to try the query from there:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#pics').bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() +
       $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
      alert('end reached');
    }
  });
});
```

However, for me it didnt work, and I decided to create a simple (very simple) page and to test if the script will work there. Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#pics').bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() +
       $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
      alert('end reached');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>YEAH SANDWICHES</h1>
<div id="pics">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="" /><br />
</div>
```

However, all images are pre-loaded and the jQuery script doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your #pics got a scrollbar?

Comment: Try putting the jquery function in $document.ready() and check...

Comment: Even though it is wrong, I have updated the HTML in your question! Replaced all the `</br>` to `<br />`. Please learn `HTML`.

Comment: @BhanuChowdary `jQuery(function($) {` is the short version of `$(document).ready() `

Comment: The first $ is unnecessary.

Comment: The `#pics` should have `overflow:scroll` and a defined height http://jsfiddle.net/vmxrca1d/9/

Comment: it's look jquery is the troubler , i think in your side baybe

Comment: `scrollHeight` is undefined.

Comment: This [http://jsfiddle.net/t55whmxb/](http://jsfiddle.net/t55whmxb/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form the docs [scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements *with the overflow CSS property set to **scroll*** (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Add these css properties to `#pics`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmxrca1d/9/)**

```
#pics{
    overflow:scroll;  //overflow-y:scroll
    height:500px
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer? `:)`

Comment: I had answered this **[way before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912016/why-my-jquery-doesnt-work/30912313#comment49861697_30912016)** your edited you deleted answer. I was just busy attaching relevant and appropriate docs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a scroll on the `#pics` to use the scroll option. I don't know why you use jScroll, but I removed it. You can use this way:

**Working Snippet**

Just go to the end of the page and check the alert!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#pics").scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('end reached');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#pics {height: 300px; overflow: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>YEAH SANDWICHES</h1>
<div id="pics">
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
  <img src="img1.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /><br />
</div>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#pics').bind('scroll', function() {
      if($(this).scrollTop() +
         $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
        alert('end reached');
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```