# How to find out in code if you've reach the end of a scrollable element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scrollable list and I would like to know when I've reached the end.

Example:

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    ....
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qtxgvccu/)

The only way I think you can find out if you've reach the end is to determine the length of all children (all the `li`s) and add the widths. I actually hope there is a smarter way to do this ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery

Comment: Yep, thats it, I just need the `scrollHeight` property