# Fire a function when passing a section - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to get a last bit of my code to work. Problem is I need to fire a function when a user scrolls past a `div`

So the structure of my html looks roughly like this

```
<div class="panel-grid-cell">
  <div id="pgc-1">...</div>
  <div id="pgc-2">...</div>
  ...
  <div id="pgc-n">...</div>
</div>
```

So the idea is when users passes a `div` with `id="pgc-1"` fire a function and so on for the rest of them.

Each of these divs has a `li a` item with the `href` attached, so I my function would look something like this

```
ga('send','event','scroll',city,$(this).text())
```

where `this` would be corresponding `li a` with the `href`

At the moments what I have is this.
A function to loop through `div`'s  and store their `id's` in array. And a build a `li a` menu.

```
 var li="";
 var linames = ["Intro","1925","1935","1945","1955","1965","1975","1985","1995","2005","Now"];
 var i = 0;
 function getSectionIDs()
 {
    $("div.panel-grid-cell").children().each(function() {
    if(linames[i] !== undefined)
    {
        li += "<li><a href='#"+$(this).attr('id')+"'>"+linames[i]+"</a></li>";           
    }
    i++;
    });
 $("ul.timeline-items").append(li);
 }
```

Now I also have a function that checks how far did I scroll and change a class for each `li` item.

```
function onScroll(event){
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('ul.timeline-items li a').each(function () {
      var currLink = $(this);
      var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
      if (refElement.position().top -75 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top+75 + refElement.height()-75 > scrollPos) {
         $('ul.timeline-items li a').removeClass("active");
         currLink.addClass("active");
      }
      else{
         currLink.removeClass("active");
      }
    });
    }
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
```

This Code does not what I want, because it constantly check If I have passed the `div` or not, but I need to fire my function only once.

Any help?

Comment: It may help you [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery).

Comment: Use `one` method of jQuery if you want to fire a method only once... refer http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: hmm, good point about `one`, need to find a smart way to attach it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself the other day,

Inside a scrolling function just put a condition when `$(document).scrollTop()` equals to `refElement.offset()`, fire a function, and it works perfectly.

Meaning that check how far user has scrolled and if this value is equals to the offset of the div, fire a function.