# Check If user is near bottom of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a check using jquery If the users scrolled near the bottom of an element. I have an element named wrapper with overflow: scroll,and ever solution i can find is about the entite document. How can you make this check in a different element than the body

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
var wantedElementBottom = $("#wanted-element").offset().top + $("#wanted-element").height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() === wantedElementBottom) {
           alert('im here')//do something
     })
   })
```