# Trigger function when an DOM we reach the end of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When we keep scrolling we will reach the end of `divOne` at a particular time. At that time I want the `divTwo` to be `relative` (Initially it is `fixed`). Here is my code. Please help

```css
.divOne {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.divTwo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: brown;
}

.divThree {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divOne"></div>
<div class="divTwo"></div>
<div class="divThree"></div>
```

Comment: `<script></script>` ... you seem to have forgot your actual code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery

Comment: That is not related. I want to trigger when the dom is scrolled to the end of the divOne. I don't want to scroll inside the divOne