# Changing background when the bottom of a div is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image, parallax

I am making a parallax style website and i want the background-image property of a div to change when i reach the bottom of a div that is 100% width of the window. How would i detect that the bottom of the div has been scrolled to with javascript/jquery? It seems really obvious but nothing i have tried has had a positive result.

I could just use scrollTop() and reference the exact pixel that the bottom of the div lands on but i want it to be responsive and be able to change if the size of the div changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
`$().scrollTop()`//how much has been scrolled
`$().innerHeight()`// inner height of the element
```

So you can take the sum of the first two properties for your div, and when it equals to the windows scrolled, you've reached the end:

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#myDiv').scrollTop() + $("#myDiv").innerHeight() ) {
       $("#myDiv").css("background","red");
  }
});
```

```css
body{
height:900px;
}

div {
height:200px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div >
Div 1
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
Div 2
</div>
<div >
Div 3
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so much simpler than what i was trying :)

Comment: Mark as the answer if it helps you