# Terms & Conditions Gem for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have a Rails application that the product team would like me to add a "Terms & Conditions" section that a new user would have to scroll through until the end, before the new user creation process is completed (I am using Devise for user management).

I did a search for a Gem, but could not find any. Anyone know of a Gem I can use, or should I write a piece of code from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you need a gem for this, just create your custom Devise view and add in a Terms & Conditions scrollable div. Then you can use something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery) to detect when they scroll to the bottom of it. Keep your submit button disabled and when you detect they reach the bottom enable it and allow them to submit.