# Detect when the end of a div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know if the end of a div element is currently visible in the users' browser.

I tried something I saw on the web, but scrollTop() always gave me zero in my Browser. I read something about an issue in Chrome, but I didn't understand quite well.

```
jQuery(
  function($) {
    $('#flux').bind('scroll', function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        alert('end reached');
      }
    })
  }
);
```

My idea is the following:

1- User loads page and sees a Bar (sticky div at bottom visible page) with some information.
2- After scrolling a bit, and reaching the end of a div element, this bar will position there, after the div. This is the bar's original position

I wasn't really able to know when I was at the end of the div element. Eventually I found this code:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#block-homepagegrid').offset().top + $('#block-homepagegrid').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
  $('.hero-special-message').removeClass('hero-special-messege-scrolling');
} else {
  $('.hero-special-message').addClass('hero-special-messege-scrolling');
}
});
```

I see that it's working, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what it does.

I know the following:

**1. $(window).scrollTop();**

this gives me the amount of pixels the user has scrolled, pretty self explanatory.

**2. $('#block-homepagegrid').offset().top;**

I THINK this is the distance  between the start of the page and the start of the div. I know it's the current coordinates, but what is top exactly here?

**3. $('#block-homepagegrid').outerHeight();**

```
this gives the height of the element, I know there are 3, like
height(), innerHeight() and outerHeight(), if you want to take into
account border, margin, padding, which is the better to use?
```

**4. window.innerHeight;**

I understand this is what the user sees, but I'm having troubles understanding why does it matter for my situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Top is the offset coordinates (the top) of the your referenced element in relation to the document.  Offset returns the top and left coordinates of a referenced element.

Comment: The answer here will explain why you need innerHeight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the native JavaScript [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). It automatically figures out what percentage of a given element is visible in the window and triggers callbacks based on that. So then you can do this:

```
function visibleHandler(entries) {
  if (entries[0].intersectionRatio >= 1.0) {
    // The whole element is visible!
  } else {
    // Part of it is scrolled offscreen!
  }
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(visibleHandler, {threshold: 1.0});
observer.observe(document.getElementById('flux'));
```

Now, whenever the element with ID `flux` is 100% in view, it will trigger the visibleHandler. It will also trigger again if it's scrolled back out of view; that's why the function checks the ratio of visibility to see if it just hit 100% or just got reduced from 100%. You could be more fancy and use the observer entry's insersectionRect, which gives you the rectangle containing the visible portion of the element, and use that to determine top/bottom visibility.