# Detect when user reaches end of div in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript but this days i have tried to write a code that detect when user reach end of div tag.
I found this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 

<head> 
  <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script> 
</head> 
<style type="text/css">
.container{width:200px;height:150px;overflow:auto;}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br>
Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br>
Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br>
Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br>
Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>

</div>

</body>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('.container').bind('scroll', function()
    {
      if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
        {
           alert('end reached');
        }
     })
  }
);
    </script>
  
</html>
```

and it works great.But when i edit code like

1. remove class
2. replace class name with id
   and now it looks like

my script is

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('#myExample').bind('scroll', function()
    {
      if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
        {
           alert('end reached');
        }
     })
  }
);
    </script>
```

and body

```
<body>
  <div id="myExample" style="margin-bottom: 1000px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br>
Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br>
Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br>
Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br>
Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>

</div>

</body>
```

It wont work now.I dont know why.Maybe because it doesn't have .container class.
I need help
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting when user scrolls to bottom of div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery)

Comment: doesn't work again.

Comment: I just checked your code and it works with `#myExample`. What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: and what do you mean? - **"It wont work now"**

Comment: @s.kuznetsov which code do you check (first or after my edit)

Comment: After your editing. Second.

Comment: did you add inline style?

Comment: I have a counter question. Have you set the selector `#myExample` instead of `.container`, inside the `<style>...</style>` tag?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov no

Comment: Then do it. Because your styles create scrolling (**overflow:auto**) by limiting the **height** and **width** of the element.

Comment: Should be so - `#myExample{width:200px;height:150px;overflow:auto;}`

Comment: ok change inline style style="width:200px;height:1000px;overflow: auto;" and it is not working

Comment: show a screenshot of the code, pls

Comment: @s.kuznetsov ok see edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227218/discussion-between-s-kuznetsov-and-nikola-marinov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `bind()`. This method is obsolete. Use `on()` method:

```
$('#myExample').on('scroll', function()
...
```

Second, to achieve scrolling, the container needs to be made smaller in relation to the size of the text. To do this, I wrapped the text in an additional `div`, giving the **id** name *myExample_text*. This `div` needs to set the desired **height** of 1000 pixels:

```
<div id="myExample_text" style="height: 1000px;">
...
</div>
```

And set the parent `div` (`#myExample`) to the smallest **height** to achieve scrolling.

Here's a complete solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
   <head>
      <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="myExample" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 1000px">
         <div id="myExample_text" style="height: 1000px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
            Consectetuer augue nibh lacus at <br>
            Pretium Donec felis dolor penatibus <br>
            Phasellus consequat Vivamus dui lacinia <br>
            Ornare nonummy laoreet lacus Donec <br>
            Ut ut libero Curabitur id <br>
            Dui pretium hendrerit sapien Pellentesque <br>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      jQuery(
        function($)
        {
          $('#myExample').on('scroll', function()
          {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
              {
                 alert('end reached');
              }
           })
        }
      );         
   </script>
</html>
```